# Java webservice complex types

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am havving an android application using ksoap2 and a java webservice running on tomcat, axis2.

There is a method in the webservice that returns:

```
public class RecipeSmallReturnType 
{
    public int      mId;
    public String   mName;
    public String   mDescription;
    public String   mUsername;
    public int      mDifficulty;
    public int      mServeCount;
    public int      mPreparationTime;
    public float    mTotalRating;
    public int      mNumOfVotes;
    public int      mOwnerId;
    public int      mUserRating;
    public int      mNumOfViews;
    public String   mReleaseDate;
}
```

When i am using the webservice on my local pc (using new-> web service etc.) I get an array of this type filled with data.

But.
When I publish it I get an array of this type - but with no data in it...

Any ideas?
Maybe I need to add some jars?
What can be the problem ?

I am stuck on this for almost a week.

Please please please I need help

I have also implemented the return type in the Android:

```
    public class RecipeSmallReturnType implements KvmSerializable
{
    public int      mId;
    public String   mName;
    public String   mDescription;
    public String   mUsername;
    public int      mDifficulty;
    public int      mServeCount;
    public int      mPreparationTime;
    public float    mTotalRating;
    public int      mNumOfVotes;
    public int      mOwnerId;
    public int      mUserRating;
    public int      mNumOfViews;
    public String   mReleaseDate;

    public Object getProperty( int param ) 
    {
        switch( param )
        {
            case 0:     return new Integer( mId );
            case 1:     return mName;
            case 2:     return mDescription;
            case 3:     return mUsername;
            case 4:     return new Integer( mDifficulty );
            case 5:     return new Integer( mServeCount );
            case 6:     return new Integer( mPreparationTime );
            case 7:     return new Float( mTotalRating );
            case 8:     return new Integer( mNumOfVotes );
            case 9:     return new Integer( mOwnerId );
            case 10:    return new Integer( mUserRating );
            case 11:    return new Integer( mNumOfViews );
            case 12:    return mReleaseDate;

            default:    return null;
        }
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() 
    {
        return 13;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo( int param, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) 
    {
        switch( param )
        {
            case 0:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mId";
                break;

            case 1:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mName";
                break;

            case 2:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mDescription";
                break;

            case 3:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mUsername";
                break;

            case 4:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mDifficulty";
                break;

            case 5:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mServeCount";
                break;

            case 6:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mPreparationTime";
                break;

            case 7:
                arg2.type   = Float.class;
                arg2.name   = "mTotalRating";
                break;

            case 8:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mNumOfVotes";
                break;

            case 9:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mOwnerId";
                break;

            case 10:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mUserRating";
                break;

            case 11:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mNumOfViews";
                break;

            case 12:
                arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name   = "mReleaseDate";
                break;

            default:    break;
        }
    }

    public void setProperty( int param, Object obj ) 
    {
        switch( param )
        {
            case 0:     mId                 = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 1:     mName               = (String)obj;  break;
            case 2:     mDescription        = (String)obj;  break;
            case 3:     mUsername           = (String)obj;  break;
            case 4:     mDifficulty         = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 5:     mServeCount         = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 6:     mPreparationTime    = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 7:     mTotalRating        = (Float)obj;   break;
            case 8:     mNumOfVotes         = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 9:     mOwnerId            = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 10:    mUserRating         = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 11:    mNumOfViews         = (Integer)obj; break;
            case 12:    mReleaseDate        = (String)obj;  break;

            default:    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

But what I get is:

```
searchRecipesNewResponse{return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; }
```

Instead of being filled with data (I get data when the webservice is not on the host but on the loacl PC)

Yoav

Answer (score 1):

implement KSerializable class  in RecipeSmallReturnType.

Comment: Implement it in the webservice or in the android? KSerializable or KvmSerliazable - it is for the return type. Why does it work on the local webservice but not on the hosting?

Comment: Ok, Its KvmSerializable and implement it in the android application, in class RecipeSmallReturnType and do a little bit search regarding to implementation details of KvmSerialization